# What is this IC on the Withings ScanWatch?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I'd really love it if someone could help me identify the IC marked 94506 R64M (or R64?) on this picture from a Reddit post about [Heart Rate Sensor Research on the Withings Scanwatch][1]

[image: Withins ScanWatch Main PCB]

I found very similar ICs both on the Surface Earbuds ([teardown link](https://www.qucox.com/microsoft-surface-earbuds-teardown/)). In there, they say that it is flash memory for storing BLE profiles but there is very little to back this up (the English is terrible bc it is translated from this [Chinese article](https://www.52audio.com/archives/51960.html))

[image: Surface Earbuds PCB]

I also found very similar chips in two other products, in a PCB from their Garmin Vector 3 from this [german forum post](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/529907)

[image: Garmin Vector 3 PCB]

and also from a teardown of the Fossil FB-01 Hybrid E-Paper Smartwatch from this [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/atc1441/status/1642121623623852032)

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance if you can help me !! (and if you cant, for having read my post at all ^^)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably [Macronix MX25R6435F NOR flash memory](https://www.mxic.com.tw/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/8868/MX25R6435F,%20Wide%20Range,%2064Mb,%20v1.6.pdf) in a 22-WLCSP package.

I couldn't find a 100% confirmation because there are no pictures of this specific configuration on the internet and the datasheet says nothing about markings, but there are some hints that lead to this conclusion:

- From the pictures we can determine that the package of the ic has dimensions of about 2x3.6 mm. This matches with the dimensions from the datasheet for the 22-WLCSP package. Even though they aren't explicit shown, we can measure them from the drawings to be about 2x3.5 mm which seems to be within tolerance.
- [This website](https://www.chipsetpro.com/de/efi-bios-chip/135-efi-bios-chip-fix-firmware-mdm-dep-bga12-a1534-emc-2991-820-00244-4770000000787.html) sells chips with a similar packaging and markings in the same style, but instead of "R64M" it reads "L64X". The website doesn't name the chip, but includes a screenshot of a datasheet that shows the dimensions. The screenshot was taken from this [datasheet](https://www.application-datasheet.com/pdf/macronix/mx25l6473embi-10g.pdf) of a Macronix "MX25**L64**73E".
- This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/13eig09/id_love_some_help_on_an_ic_identification_on_the/) in which you asked the same question and the same conclusion was reached.